# Is an attack of opportunity granted when a summon appears within one's threatened area?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack, summoning

If a character casts [summon monster](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/summonMonster.html#_summon-monster-i) and summons the monster immediately next to another creature, does that creature get an attack of opportunity?

The spell states *“It appears where you designate and acts immediately, on your turn.”*, but does the appearance count as a movement by the summon (*à la* *teleport*), which would then grant an attack of opportunity?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No attack of opportunity is granted.**

According to the [Pathfinder's RSD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attacks-of-Opportunity) attacks of opportunity are triggered only by:

- **moving out of** a square in the threatened area of a hostile creature. Exceptions are: the 5-ft. step, the withdraw action, and teleportation (but not necessarily *casting* a teleport spell).
- **performing a distracting act** while in a square in the threatened area of a hostile creature. This usually include:

  - attacking with a ranged weapon,
  - attacking unarmed,
  - delivering a *coup de grace*,
  - performing a combat maneuver,
  - casting a spell,
  - using a touch spell (if the spell is harmful you are considered armed; you don't draw AoO from the target, but sill draw from other enemies)
  - activating a spell-like ability,
  - activating a spell-completion magic item,
  - drinking a potion or applying an oil,
  - loading a crossbow,
  - moving heavy objects around,
  - picking up objects,
  - sheathing a weapon,
  - retrieving a stored item,
  - standing up from prone,
  - escaping from a net,
  - locking or unlocking a weapon to a gauntlet,
  - preparing to throw a splash weapon,
  - running,
  - using many skills.

Appearing into a square because of a summoning spell seems to not fall in these two categories.

However, appearing in the middle of a fight may or may not be considered *a distracting act*, according to how your group interpret Summoning effects.